# Make function accept generic input, return value with same keys, but with values from another type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following types

```js
type A = {
  foo: number
  bar: number
}

type B = {
  foo: string
  bar: string
}
```

And I want to write a function `f()` that takes a parameter that is completely or partially type A, and outputs an object with the same keys, but with types from type B.

For example,

```js
f(a) = {foo: 1, bar: 2}
// should have return type {foo: string, bar: string}
f(a) = {foo: 1}
// should have return type {foo: string}
f(a) = {bar: 1}
// should have return type {bar: string}
```

I have tried to use generics, but since typescript doesn't check for extra fields, I get an error when I use `keyof`:

```js
function f<T extends A>(input: T): {[K in keyof T]: B[K]} {
  //      Type 'K' cannot be used to index type 'B' ^^^^^

  // ... function implementation here
}
```

If this solution is to work, I'll have to somehow restrict `T` to only being a subset of type `A`, though I haven't found a way to do it that makes the compiler understand `keyof T` can index `A`.

The closest I have come is to using `Partial`, but again that is not exactly the behavior I want:

```js
function f(input: Partial<A>): Partial<B> {
  // mock implementation, output does not matter, asking about types here
  const res: Partial<B> = {};
  let k: keyof typeof input;
  for (k in input) {
    const v = input[k];
    res[k] = parseInt(v ?? "0");
  }
  return res;
}
```

This is incorrect because the following inputs all give outputs of the same type:

```js
const a = f({})
const b = f({foo: 1})
const c = f({bar: 2})
// a, b, c all have type {foo?: number, bar?: number)

// should be:
// a: {}
// b: {foo: string}
// c: {bar: string}
```

Is what I'm asking for possible in Typescript right now? Any solutions/workarounds would be much appreciated.

Comment: You probably want `f` to be generic in the keys `K` and use the equivalent of `Pick<A, K>` and `Pick<B, K>` as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wgAy1m).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Wow, that was fantastic, exactly what I was looking for. It does fully address the question I asked. If possible, could I also ask how you would implement this functionality for two nested layers? Perhaps I'll understand after seeing your response. Thanks so much.

Comment: "two nested layers"? You'd presumably need something more complex, but without a [mre] I wouldn't know what specifically to suggest.  Given that this is a followup question I'm considering it out of scope here, so I won't worry any more about it.  If, after this question is answered, you have an additional followup issue, you might want to post a new question so that it can be addressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion here is to make the function `f()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type of the keys `K` of the `input` parameter, and then you can represent the `input` as `Pick<A, K>` and the output type as `Pick<B, K>`, using  [the `Pick<T, K>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys):

```
declare function f<K extends keyof A>(input: Pick<A, K>): Pick<B, K>;
```

Or you can inline the definition of `Pick` to get the following version:

```
declare function f<K extends keyof A>(input: { [P in K]: A[K] }): { [P in K]: B[K] };
```

Let's test it out:

```
const b0 = f({ foo: 1, bar: 2 });
/* const b0: {
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
} */

const b1 = f({ foo: 1 });
/* const b1: {
    foo: string;
} */

const b2 = f({ bar: 1 });
/* const b2: {
    bar: string;
} */
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeBYAUFTUBmB7XAXFAHYCuAtgEYQBO6WUlAhjUWVbegL7rqiRQAQgmT0seQlADOwGgEtiAczGZmrabIXK0PNOgAmEAMYAbFtGyliR4HNzEcAHgDSUCAA9gEYvqlQA1hAguNiwAHwAFApgpMBESFAA2gAKUApQzgC6RDCJWVBcAJTxSanpWUSCeZkFANzoAPQNUIam5jhWNnYO2C5unt6+AUEh4VHEMXFQyXJG-o4wADQZYcXTs-OCy85htVBN0kzk0MAAFlq8emhG9jKMAAwi2BEJEkQAjMtqRABMBYX1NANABUUBuxDulHu8RUOHwRBk8iUgIY3w0SMUgK4UGBDUu4Mh7yeLzhkiJRUBILBt2AjHeMIw4nh6K0WJxeKuBNplD+iGeCTR5IBjVBXMYPwZqJYCM0yO47PQQA)